# Any hardware/software routers that support Full Cone NAT?

Tags: nat, ipv6, teredo

i'm trying to get Teredo to function on my machine.

Most routers, it seems, refuse to forward packets from any host other than the one i specifically connected to first. [Teredo](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Teredo_tunneling) requires [full Cone NAT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_address_translation) in order to function.

Does any router, hardware or software, allow full cone NAT?

Is this an oversight by the designers of Teredo that nobody, in practice, can use it?

---

i've tried

- m0n0wall
- pfsense
- D-Link
- Linksys
- SMC

Answer (score 2):

Some routers have a "gaming mode" that will turn on full cone NAT

Answer (score 1):

I've never had Teredo fail behind any NAT, even dodgy old Checkpoint.

I don't have much more info then that as all the Linux NAT's I use now have 6to4 enabled and advertised giving native IPv6 to clients.

Comment: 6to4 on the router itself. i never actually thought about that. Although, the hope is that a machine behind the firewall gets to appear as though it's directly connected to the internet - bypassing all firewall rules.

Answer (score 0):

According to [this](http://markmail.org/message/jvjor3gj4vym6hpo) post, in a 1-1 scenario maybe SNAT and DNAT will be sufficient in netfilter to make a full cone nat.

Answer (score 0):

you can use Wive-NG firmware with supported router, or other - DD/Opeb-WRT. It's fully customized & supports NAT.

Comment: im unsure, what your answer will solve?

Answer (score -1):

I had a similar problem with 3cx PBX it insisted on full cone NAT so I used a Draytek router. Worked a treat